# reflection API is throwing no such method exception while migrating to java 9

Tags: java, reflection, java-9

I am migrating to java 9 from java 8
I was using reflection to fetch method 'getStackTraceElement(int)' from class 'java.lang.Throwable'
And I was setting the accessibility to "true".

programs works fine for java 8
but when I migrated to java 9 ,
It started failing with error 
    'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceElement(int) . '

I have the code which works fine in java 8 as following
private static Method m;

```
'public static void main(String args[])
{
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("here1");
        //next line throws error
        m = Throwable.class.getDeclaredMethod("getStackTraceElement",int.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("here2");
    } catch (Exception e) {

        //logger.warn(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        System.out.println("==>"+e.getLocalizedMessage);
        System.out.println("==>"+e.getName);
        System.out.println("==>"+e.getStackTraceElement);
        System.out.println("here3");
    }
}'
```

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: Don't you mean `getStackTrace` method?

Comment: The API has been removed from `Throwable` class. It was anyway `native`, what were you actually using it for? The current code doesn't show much of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They have introduced a class in Java 9 specifically for this purpose called the `StackWalker`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `Throwable` class java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html you will see that the `getStackTraceElement` is removed from the class which is the reason why you are getting this error.

As mentioned by Demozo, use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html.

Comment: "getStackTraceElement is removed from the class which" is misleading as getStackTraceElement(int) was a non-public method so nothing should be make direct use of it.